# How to downgrade sourcetree back to 1.9.x?

Tags: windows-7, sourcetree

I thought that maybe upgrading sourcetree to the newest version would rid me of some really annoying bugs. But I was wrong - known bugs got worse and new major issues appeared (for example, the app cannot be restored after being minimized for a while).

I tried to run the old version, but it seems to have been replaced with the new, broken version. Is there a correct approach to going back - without breaking even more stuff?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what OS this is on, but i will provide potential solutions for different OS's. For linux (system package) use "yum/apt/whatever remove (package)" Then find the package version you want online.  For windows, use WinKey+R and run "control", select "Uninstall A Program", uninstall said program, then find the version you would like online.

Comment: It's windows 7, but maybe this answer might help someone else.